# How to fast the scripts with up to 3400 machines?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fabric

I have 3400 machines neet to send data to graphite , but my scripts takes abount 5 min to complete, how can I reduce it to 3 or 2 minutes,thank you ,code below

```
def sendmsg(hostname,metric):
        a = mntdir + hostname + '/' + metric + '_median'
        with settings(hide('running'), warn_only=True):
            valueMedian = local(("cat %s|grep %s|awk '{print $2}'") % (a,now),capture=True)
            local(("echo %s.%s_Median_90days %s %s >/dev/udp/20.26.2.18/2001 ") % (hostname,metric,valueMedian,unixdate))


if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
        localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        now1 = date.strftime("%H:%M")
        print now1
        now2 = date.strftime("%M")
        with settings(hide('running'), warn_only=True):
            unixdate = local("date +%s",capture=True)
        if int(now2) % 5 == 0:
            now = now1 + ':00'
            p=Pool(100)
            print now
            for hostname in host:
                for metric in metrics:
                    p.apply_async(sendmsg, args=(hostname,metric))
            starttime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
            print('Waiting for all job done...%s' % starttime)
            p.close()
            p.join()
            stoptime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
            print('sending completed...%s ' % stoptime)
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: What does your *local* function do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/foo/ {print $2}' file
```

does roughly the same as your

```
cat file | grep foo | awk '{print $2}'
```

and avoids creating two processes, which might help slightly.

Comment: `grep foo file | …` (useless use of cat)

Comment: haha,it reduced to 3+ minutes,any other suggestions lol, 2minutes will much better

Comment: @KlausD., that's's exactly what Ulrich recommended - **dropping this form**

Comment: @Flasking, If you're using *plumbum* - you may try to use its *grep* command directly.